# Have Windows XP Explore option default Windows Explorer path

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Is there a way to automatically set the default path that Windows Explorer opens up to in Windows XP?  My computer always opens to C:\Documents and Settings{user name}\Start Menu.  I typically work on a project and then finish that project a few weeks later.  And I generally don't open Windows Explorer to other paths unless someone comes to my desk asking about something else, so this is very inconvenient.

I found this, but I'd like to know the specific workflow and command, so a reader coming to this questions can quickly answer their question.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853

**Screen shot:**

[image]

Comment: Explorer always opens to your Start menu folder when you right-click the Start menu and click Explore, because you are telling Windows you want to explore the Start menu.

Comment: That makes sense.  I wonder if there is a way to put a custom option in there that says "Explore Folder X", similar to what I have in my screen shot for Git and 7-Zip options?  Do you know how to do that?  I'm just looking to make it more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Explorer (in XP).  Use Tools, Folder Options:

[image: XP Folder options]

Go back to the File Types tab, and go to Folder.  Click Advanced.

[image: XP Folder set]

Click "New". Set the action name, and the command line.

[image: Details of folder settings]

I also often set "Explore" to the default, so that double-clicking on My Computer or a folder opens in Explorer view.  Also, this change can be done in the registry without adding a new action, by modifying the "Explore" command, but I prefer to add the new action.